# How to post json request to Ruby with merge current_user.id

Tags: ruby, json, merge, request, session-cookies

I`m not experienced in Ruby on Rails. I have a running web application that I want to access with an android application. I use json for the requests from my mobile app.

I can login with a post request. After that I want to buy some products. So I have to update the data. For this I want to take a create method from ruby with the `order_controller`. The method looks like:

```
@order = Order.create(params.require(:order)
        .permit(ordered_products_attributes: [:quantity, :product_id])
        .merge(user_id: current_user.id))
```

The first part I can copy with java, but I don`t know how I have to get the "merge" part with the`current_user.id`.

When I observe the terminal when I buy something with the web app, I only see the same statement what I can copy with java for the json request.
When I send the post request I get an error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):

So I tried to post the cookie in header I get during the login. I get the same error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does "I can copy with java" mean?

Comment: How is the `current_user` populated?  Are you sending credentials with each request to handle finding the correct user?  `current_user` is likely `nil` here, so you get the exception.

Comment: My json post request in java looks like the request the web app`s look like in the terminal from the ruby environment.Processing by OrdersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "order"=>{"ordered_pro
ducts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"1", "product_id"=>11}, ... ,"13"=>{"quantity"=>"0
", "product_id"=>11}}}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

NoMethodError (undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Thats my big problem, I don`t know much about ruby. I think the current_user is defined in devise lib. But I didn`t found it yet. I have to get the current user in my request but I don`t know how it has to look like.

Comment: Ok, so you're using devise.  You need to log a user in before you serve the request.  How does your JSON API handle authentication?  With devise something simple is to use something like this gem: https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication

Comment: I comment the token of devise #config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token because I don`t know how I can build it in java for the request. Before the comment the login was allways failed.

Comment: Well then you have work to do. How is the rails app supposed to know who the order is for?

Comment: I hoped that I can give the user_id from the session. Only the user id is not so safe. Or I can give a token_authentication_key in the header. Mybe something like that: I can give the authentication in the header: postMethod.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationString); But I don`t know how to generate the right algorithm for the authorizationString.

Comment: What does ruby exactly needs in my json post request?

Comment: Often the token is just another JSON field. You really need to define that before this will work at all. This is something your application has to deal with, devise is only going to help here. Check out that gem I posted above.

Comment: Okay, trank you! I will try it.